# How to combine a Backbonejs router with Twitter bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, tabs

I've got some jQuery code combined with bootstrap in which I want to change some stuff around so that I can use Backbone.js. I've come quite far, but now I'm having some trouble with the tabs that I use. I basically used [this Twitter bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). I managed to show the contents of the tab, but the tab itself doesn't look like it is active, which kind of lets the user in the dark about which tab is actually open). So what I'm after is making the tab look active.

The tabs themselves are defined like this:

```
<a id="tab1" href="#/ticket/1">1 Blah Blah</a>
```

I used to use this code to set the tab to active:

```
$("#pageTab").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Unfortunately I changed the routes of the tabs using Backbone.js and I then try to show the contents of the tab like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "ticket/:ticketId": "ticket"
    }
});

var router = new Router();
router.on("route:ticket", function(ticketId) {
    tabContentView.render({ticketId: ticketId}); // This works
    $(this).tab('show'); // This does not work
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

I guess the trouble is that `this` doesn't refer to the tab itself here. So I tried to do it using:

```
$("#tab"+ticketId).tab('show');
```

but unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

Does anybody know how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Is there no way of getting the click event on the url from the router so that I can use it with `.tab("show");`?

Comment: because $(this) its not node in this context. IMHO you should encapsulate bootstrap interaction in view and run it on view render. render: function(){ // make html; this.$el.tab('show') }

Comment: @Evgeniy - Thanks for your idea, but I'm kinda lost in what you say. Would you have an example of that?

Comment: checkout this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nFbf2/ you can pass id from router to select necessary tab and render a view

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of 'getting a click event in a router', but you could always decide to trigger a click event on the desired tab yourself.

```
router.on("route:ticket", function(ticketId) {
    tabContentView.render({ticketId: ticketId});
    $("#tab" + ticketId).trigger('click');
}
```